# All of md files are showing in root structure instead of a hierarchy in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I have a project with this structure:

```
project
│   README.md
│   main.md   
│
└───folder1
│   │   item1.md
│   │   item2.md
│   │
│   └───subfolder1
│       │   item3.md
│       │   item4.md
│       │   ...
│   
└───folder2
    │   item5.md
    │   item6.md
```

But, all of these files are showing in the root directory without any hierarchy.
Instead of following the above structure, I get this structure:

```
project
    │   REAMME.md
    │   main.md
    │   item1.md
    │   item2.md
    │   item3.md
    │   item4.md
    │   item5.md
    │   item6.md
```

How can i Get this said structure in documentation of doxygen?

Comment: which version of doxygen? What is in your doxygen settings file different from the default settings (`doxygen -x Doxyfile`)? In principle the behavior is logical the files are just pages and have no structure, they look like to have a structure by means of the directories. When you want some structure you will probably need some section / subsections etc and or page / subpafe in your files.

Comment: I did not change anything in config file except the input and output directories. What tag can i use to get the following structure?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no tag for this just with the mentioned commands you can mimic it

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to mimic it by means of the layout file (see: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout).

I have create the following structure:

```
project
│   fil_0_1.md
│
└───dir_1
│   │   fil_1_1.md
│   │   fil_1_2.md
│
└───dir_2
│   │   fil_2_1.md
│   │   fil_2_2.md
```

and I adjusted the `DoxygenLayout.xml`, obtained by `doxygen -l DoxygenLayout.xml` by adding the lines:

```
<tab type="user" url="\ref md_fil_0_1" title="fil_0_1"/>
<tab type="usergroup" title="dir_1">
  <tab type="user" url="\ref md_dir_1_fil_1_1" title="fil_1_1"/>
  <tab type="user" url="\ref md_dir_1_fil_1_2" title="fil_1_2"/>
</tab>
<tab type="usergroup" title="dir_2">
  <tab type="user" url="\ref md_dir_2_fil_2_1" title="fil_2_1"/>
  <tab type="user" url="\ref md_dir_2_fil_2_2" title="fil_2_2"/>
</tab>
```

just after the line:

```
    <tab type="examples" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
```

I also changed the line:

```
<tab type="pages" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
```

into

```
<tab type="pages" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
```

This resulted in:

[image]

Some remarks about:

```
tab type="user" url="\ref md_dir_1_fil_1_1" title="fil_1_1"/>
```

- `url` the `\ref` requires a doxygen anchor  and this is here build from the directory name plus the file name. You can also the anchor when using `doxygen -d markdown` as at the firs line you will see something like `@page md_dir_1_fil_1_1 fil_1_1\ilinebr File 1 in directory 1` and here the `md_dir_1_fil_1_1`  is the anchor.
- `title` is just free text`